# How to block android apps from being run on Emulators like Nox?

Tags: android, security, emulation, block

I'm having a hard time when trying to block my app from being run on emulators, especially when we talk about Nox Emulator.

I've tried some of the most popular answers about this question, like this one:

```
public static boolean isEmulator() {
    return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
            || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
            || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
            || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
            || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there a "modern way" of blocking android apps from being run on emulators?

Comment: Did you observe logs when running on Nox emulator?

Comment: Also, have you tried printing out values of `Build` constants when running on Nox?

Comment: Yes, I did. It emulates a Samsung device. None of the Build constants refer a emulator.

Comment: how about [framgia/android-emulator-detector](https://github.com/framgia/android-emulator-detector)?

Comment: another tactics recently found used by a malware is [to use motion detector](https://www.cyberscoop.com/android-malware-motion-detection-trend-micro/), if it found that the device don't move at all, the malware assumes its ran in emulator and stops its activity.

Comment: @EricWong I've tried this library, but it doesn't block Nox emulator, as you can see in the Github issue of this library. This second strategy is awesome, but can you think in a good way of using it?

Comment: as long as you have a legitimate reason, it's a good use ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeLimaPereira did you know a good way how to prevent app run on nox ?

Comment: I'm using Dexprotrctor from Licel. It's a paid tool, but it's working well